# Webstorm template string html format with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, webstorm

In the WebStorm 2016.1 release notes they have this image.

[image]

[See here](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/#angular-2)

But when I try to type this mine looks like this

[image]

Do I have to manually enter the tabs to make this happen? Shouldn't it auto format?  If so, how do I set up auto formatting?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Angular2HTML Fragment editor. With your cursor positioned inside your inline template, you should see an orange exclamation popup. In this should be an option to "Edit Angular2HTML Fragment".

[image]

I'm using the latest version of WebStorm 2016.1

Comment: That's awesome.  Do you know if there's any way to just enable this behavior inline? So I wouldn't have to use the side editor?

Comment: @taylorstine, sorry I have no idea. I only stumbled upon this as a result of your question. I was a bit frustrated with inline templates for this reason as well. Post back if you find a way!

Comment: If anyone knows how to get rid if the sickly green background in the dark theme let me know as well.

Comment: I was able to change the editor background in: settings->Editor->Color & Fonts ->General->Text->Default text->Background. Sorry, comments do not support screenshot image.

Comment: To get rid of icky background color in markup fragment (WS 2016.2.1, Darkula theme): File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General. Under Code -> Injected language fragment: Uncheck the 'background' checkbox or change to the color of your liking.